# Winapi edit controls disappear when moving window outside of the screen

Tags: c++, winapi, controls, edit

I'm creating several `EDIT` elements with a `for` loop. When I move the window outside the screen and then back inside, the `EDIT` controls disappear, along with a line in the `WM_PAINT` event.

The "create" event:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    for( int i =0; i < 4; i++ ){
        text = CreateWindow("EDIT","text",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 0,i*40+100,100,10, hwnd , NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    // Other elements
    break;
```

The "paint" event:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        SetRect(&secondbackground, 0, 70, 800, 500);
        FillRect(hdc, &secondbackground, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,200,200)) );
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        SetRect(&secondbackground, 0, 0, 800, 20);
        FillRect(hdc, &secondbackground, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,100,200)) );
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        MoveToEx(hdc,1,52,NULL);
        LineTo(hdc,100,200);
        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );

        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        SetPixel(hdc,300,300,RGB(255,255,255));
        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
    }
    break;
```

Comment: There are mismatching `BeginPaint` / `EndPaint` calls and brush resource leak

Comment: You shouldn't be using `GetDC()` inside of `WM_PAINT` at all. `BeginPaint()` gives you an `HDC`, ALL of your drawing should be done using that `HDC` only. Call `BeginPaint()` once at the beginning of `WM_PAINT`, use the `HDC` as needed, and then call `EndPaint()` before exiting the event: `hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps ); FillRect(hdc, ...); FillRect(hdc, ...); MoveToEx(hdc,...); LineTo(hdc,...); SetPixel(hdc, ...); EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );`

Answer (score 0):

Use BeginPaint/EndPaint when handling WM_PAINT, that will force background drawing which GetDC does not.